# How can a WPF user control be made to scale automatically when the parent Winforms window resizes?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I need to add a WPF user control to my existing legacy Winforms application, such that the contents of the user control scale automatically to the size of the main application window.

I see that embedding WPF user controls inside Winforms is possible by using System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost, but can this container resize the contents of my user control?

Comment: Use `ViewBox` that surround your `UserControl` ... When the parent's Height or Width increases, it will scale automatically...

Comment: Thanks Sankarann, that worked! I knew about ViewBox, but I thought that ElementHost required a UserControl, when it fact it accepts any UIElement.

Comment: @Sankarann, if you want to write an answer for this, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ViewBox` that surround your `UserControl` ... When the parent's Height or Width increases, it will scale automatically according the Height or Width...

In the Case of `ViewBox`, It will be proportional to Height and Width...